# Data Structure for high dimensional data with nullable coordinates

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, space-partitioning

Are there alternatives to uniform grid spatial partitioning when considering data structures for data with nullable or missing coordinate values?

For example with uniform grid spatial partitioning it is fairly trivial to extend it to allow nulls:
Given a point P in nullable R3, (x?, y? ,z?), like (5, null, 1) we can assign this point a bin (i?, j?, k?) like (2, null, 1). We can then search neighboring bins by slicing the data structure like 
`bins[i-1:i+1 or null, :, k-1:k+1 or null]` (assuming that j bin coordinate was null). 
Basically, in the null dimensions the point becomes a hyper-plane of sorts.

This is more of an academic question. I can probably use the spatial partitioning approach just fine, but wanted to know if someone might be familiar with alternatives.